# how to wait for element to display

Tags: protractor

how to wait until element is display :
I am using following:

```
this.IncList = element.all(by.repeater("incident in $ctrl.allIncidents"));

browser.wait(IncList.count() > 0, 10000,"Element not visible timing out");
```

and Getting following error:

```
 Failed: fn is not a function[0m
 Stack:
TypeError: fn is not a function
    at C:\Local_E2E\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:720:12
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Local_E2E\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:130:15)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
From: Task: <anonymous>
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Local_E2E\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:130:15)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
From: Task: Element not visible timing out
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.wait (C:\Local_E2E\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:716:21)
```

Comment: Is there any other way to wait for element to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ExpectedConditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) to wait for visibility, or a [number of other conditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html). Something like this should work for you:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
this.IncList = element.all(by.repeater("incident in $ctrl.allIncidents"));
// visibility of the _one_ of the elements
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this.IncList.first()), 10000,"Element not visible timing out");
```

Comment: Thanks @Brine this helped.